# Proof of existence of a rational number such that $2-\epsilon < q^2 < 2$ with the Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that, in the context of Dedekind cuts, for $\alpha = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p <= 0$ or $p^2 < 2\}$, $\alpha\alpha$ equals 2. My sketch of the proof:

Let's think about $\{qq\prime: q, q\prime \in \alpha+\}$ where $\alpha+= \alpha \bigcap \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p > 0\}$. $\{qq\prime: q, q\prime \in \alpha+\} \subset \alpha\alpha$ is almost trivial. However, the reverse side does not. I'm stuck at this point:

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a rational number $q$ such that $2-\epsilon < q^2 < 2$, with the Dedekind's construction of $\mathbb{R}$. Proving this would lead to the conclusion of the proof. Maybe with some clever technique, it would be possible to show that there exists $q = f(\epsilon)$ such that $q^2 < 2$, but I couldn't think of any. It would suffice to show the existence only, but is there any way to do that? Any help would be grateful!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could compare $1^2, 1.4^2, 1.41^2, 1.414^2, 1.4142^2, \ldots$ with $2$, and then formalise this.

Comment: If $\epsilon > 0$, then $\frac 1\epsilon > 0$. But the Archimedian principle, there is an $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n > \frac 1\epsilon$. Thus $0 < \frac 1n < \epsilon$ and $2 - \epsilon < 2 -\frac 1n < 2$. Now note that $n^2 > n$ ...